# babelbib "disables" substitution in English, but not in German

Tags: babel, substitution

I have a really weird problem: When changing the `babel` language in combination with the use of `babelbib`, certain substitutions stop working altogether. It took me hours to track down this cause. Consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}

\makeatletter

\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\section*{{\@title}}
This is the {\@title} document.

\end{document}
```

This yields a nice document:

[image: This document is fine]

If I add the `babelbib` package like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib}

\makeatletter

\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\section*{{\@title}}
This is the {\@title} document.

\end{document}
```

the substitution of `\@title` stops working:

[image: This document is incorrect]

Funny enough, this problem does not appear when the `babel` language is set to German:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib}

\makeatletter

\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\section*{{\@title}}
This is the {\@title} document.

\end{document}
```

This yields a perfectly fine document:

[image: This document is fine too]

Similarly, using `ngerman` for `babel`, but removing `babelbib`, does not exhibit this problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib}

\makeatletter

\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\section*{{\@title}}
This is the {\@title} document.

\end{document}
```

[image: This document is fine too]

My question now is: What is happening here and how can I fix it? I have German documents which use `babel` and `babelbib` that I need to translate to English. When changing the `babel` language and replacing some text, the substitutions stop working as shown in the example below. Is there a way to use `babelbib` with English as `babel` language without this problem?

Leaving the `babel` language at German is not an option since I need the language-specific terms of reference lists, table of contents etc. I am using the latest MiKTeX (32-bit) on Windows 7 and just updated all packages, in case it matters.

Comment: You're abusing `\@title`.

Comment: Is it not o.k. to access the defined `title` like this? If so, what is the proper way to access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to `babel.def` that does

```
\AtEndOfPackage{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \@ifpackageloaded{hhline}%
      {\expandafter\ifx\csname normal@char\string:\endcsname\relax
       \else
         \makeatletter
         \def\@currname{hhline}\input{hhline.sty}\makeatother
       \fi}%
      {}}}
```

Your `\makeatletter` before `\begin{document}` is so neutralized when `\makeatother` is executed at the begin document hook.

In any case, your approach is wrong, because it's not recommendable to set a document with `\makeatletter` in force.

The solution for having the title available in the document is much simpler. Add

```
\makeatletter
\def\title#1{%
  \gdef\@title{#1}%
  \global\let\thetitle\@title
}
\makeatother
```

and use `\thetitle` in the document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib}

\makeatletter
\def\title#1{%
  \gdef\@title{#1}%
  \global\let\thetitle\@title
}
\makeatother


\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\section*{\thetitle}
This is the {\thetitle} document.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your idea with `\thetitle` should make into `latex.ltx` ;-)